# Ruby double splat 'expects one argument'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does this function 'expect one' argument?

```
def resolve(name, **args) 
  ....
end
```

```
resolve(:test, foo: 123, bar: 456)
```

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Comment: What version of Ruby, and are you certain you're calling the `resolve` you think you are? Works fine for me under 2.6.5.

Comment: Works for me too with 2.6.3

Comment: Suspect this is Ruby 3., which no longer allows this syntax. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

Comment: @debugger: The only situation where that raises an error in ruby 3 is if you pass a keyword argument as the 1st parameter. So, `resolve(x: 42, ...)` will raise `ArgumentError`. But, as written, @GN's example works in 3.0.2.